# Limit in $W_{p} ^2$ implies limite in $L^{q}$.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $u_{m}\in W_{p} ^{2} \cap W_{q} ^{2}$ be such that $u_{m} \rightarrow u$ in $W_{p} ^2$.
Note that the domain $\Omega$ is a polygon.
I want to show $$u_{m} \rightarrow u \text{ in } L^{q}$$.
My textbook says this is because of Sobolev imbedding.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm using my cell, so I just gave a brief explanation. I'll edit later when I get to my desktop.

Comment: I guess $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$?

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes!

Comment: Is $\Omega$ bounded and two-dimensional? Is $p \in (1,\infty)$?

Comment: @gerw yes! Both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a (bounded) polygon. In particular, $\Omega$ possesses a Lipschitz boundary. For all $p >1 $, you have that $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded (by the Sobolev embedding theorem) in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. That is, there is $C > 0$ with
$$ \|u - u_m \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \le C \, \| u - u_m \|_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)} \to 0.$$